# Scaling of Harnack inequality

Tags: calculus, partial-differential-equations, regularity-theory-of-pdes

It is well known that if $u$ is a positive harmonic function in $B_R$, there exists $C>0$ such that 
$$
\sup_{B_{R/2}} u \leq C \inf_{B_{R/2}} u.
$$
Moreover, for every $\delta \in (0,1)$, one can slightly refined the previous result by showing 
$$
\sup_{B_{(1-\delta)R}} u \leq \frac{C}{\delta^n} \inf_{B_{(1-\delta)R}} u.
$$
This estimate can be easily computed in the case of harmonic functions by using the representation formula of $u$ in $B_R$. Does exist a similar inequality (the case $\delta \in (0,1)$) for the case of solution of a linear non-divergence form uniformly elliptic equation
$$
\sum_{ij}a_{ij}(x) D_{ij} u =0 \quad\mbox{in }B_R?
$$
Moreover, in the case of non-negative supersolution of this last equation, one can prove the so called weak Harnack inequality, i.e. there exists $C$ such that
$$
\left(\frac{1}{|B_{R/2}|}\int_{B_{R/2}}u^\varepsilon \right)^{1/\varepsilon} \leq C \inf_{B_{R/2}}u.
$$
In this setting, is it possibile to have a similar estimate in $B_{(1-\delta)R}$ with the explicit constant?